# Instantiate a class with generic type T known as a name not type

Tags: c#, generics, types

I have the following code

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassC<ClassD> objC=new ClassC<ClassD>();
        var tTypeName = "MyProject.ClassD";
        ClassC<Type.GetType(tTypeName)>=new ClassC<Type.GetType(tTypeName)>();
    }
}

public class ClassC<T>
{
    ///some code here
}

public class ClassD
{
    ///some code here
}
```

I will instantiate classc if I know the type T is ClassD like this

```
 ClassC<ClassD> objC=new ClassC<ClassD>();
```

What if I know it during runtime, how can I pass ClassD type name to classc. I tried the following, it throw compilation error, Please advice.

```
var tTypeName = "MyProject.ClassD";
ClassC<Type.GetType(tTypeName)>=new ClassC<Type.GetType(tTypeName)>
```

Comment: You would have to use `Activator` and Reflection when resolving types at runtime.

Comment: Thank you @hatchet I was searching for an answer and didn't get into this thread until now. This helps me resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reflection. Something like...

```
var myType = typeof(ClassC<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] {typeof(ClassD)});
var constructor = myType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
object instance = constructor.Invoke(new object[0]);
```